# in iOS10, screen-off will call the DidExitRegion even if the iPhone is definitely beside the beacon

Tags: ios, ibeacon, ios10, beacon

When screen is on (no matter lock or unlock) , it works correctly for DidEnterRegion and DidExitRegion.

However, when screen is off, it's so weird that even there're no any changes for the beacon and iPhone, **the app will receive the DidExitRegion call in several seconds**.

Nevertheless, when the screen is on (by pressing the home or power button, or some notifications coming to enlighten the screen, no need to unlock), the app will immediately receive DidEnterRegion call afterwards.

Anyone found that and can help? Thx.

Comment: This certainly sounds like a new bug introduced in iOS 10.  Do you have an iOS 9 device to run the same app on to verify the problem does not happen on the earlier OS version?

Comment: iOS 9 works perfect. Btw, some iPhones w/ iOS 10 work okay.

Comment: iPhone 6s is better than 6...

Comment: See my updated answer about the deployment target.  I'm curious if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** There are a number of anecdotal reports of beacon detection problems on iOS 10, with some users reporting that **setting the app deployment target in XCode to 9.x will resolve the issue.**  See here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39641127/1461050

The exit events sound like the Bluetooth stack is in a bad state.  You might try resetting it as described in my related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39572251/1461050