# Beacon monitoring after reboot with iOS10

Tags: ibeacon, ios10, beacon

With iOS9, my app was able to detect beacons even iPhone was restarting.

With iOS10 this feature is no more working. It seems that with iOS10 "monitored beacon list" is not restarted agter a phone reboot.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

There have been a number of reports of failing to monitor beacons in the background after an upgrade to iOS 10.  Try this:

1. Setting -> General -> Reset -> Reset Network Settings
2. Launch your app, verifying beacon detection in the foreground
3. Turn off your beacon or leave range to verify region exit in the foreground
4. Put the app to the background (hit home or kill the app)
5. Turn on the beacon or go within proximity
6. Wait up to 15 minutes for a didEnterRegion event, especially after reboot

Comment: It seems the pb is due to the minimum iBeacon advertising time required to detect a beacon. The frequency / duration seems have changed between iOS9 and iOS10. Any information for minimum duration / frequency ?

Comment: Do you have multiple apps detecting beacons on your phone?  Only the first 30 regions monitored across all apps get accelerated detection and the remainder fall back to a software scan approximately every 15 minutes.  Upgrading the OS may have changed which apps get the accelerated slots.  Removing and reinstalling  beacon apps can correct this.

Comment: @davidgyoung Do you have any sources for this?

Comment: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/04/21/max-beacon-regions-ios.html

Answer (score 0):

i can confirm having the same issue since using **iOS 10**. I’m using **ibeacon** with IOS10 and cannot handle the ExitRegion/EnterRegion events : 
i’ve tried to change the beacons advertising with  250 ms

The exit/enter Region sometimes it works sometimes it doesn’t. If it works you should wait up to 15 minutes for a EnterRegion event!

the most common result on iOS 10 is nothing happens, is no region events are fired, just ranging and then it stops!

I will post any replies if i make some progress
The devices tested are iPhone 6S iPhone 5S version iOS 10.0.2