# Cant detect iBeacon in iOS 10 after setting up monitoring

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ibeacon

I've been working on detecting iBeacons on iOS 10 with swift 3 and Xcode 8.2.1.

I've been following [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/location/how-to-detect-ibeacons) tutorial and so far i've been able to get the beacons detected in the foreground.
However, what i need is for the beacons to be detected in the background as well as when the app is closed.

I've set the key `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in `info.plist` and also added `Location updates` in the apps `Background Modes`.

I'm also requesting `requestAlwaysAuthorization` from the user.

Everything works fine till i add the following statement to the code: `locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)`

After i add the above statement and run the code, my app detects the beacon in the foreground and prints me a message. But as soon as i minimise the app and reopen it, the app cant seem to find the beacon. If i comment the line out and then rerun my program, the app detects the beacon in foreground as well as when i minimise and reopen the app again.
I don't understand what i'm doing wrong.

Here is my `ViewController` code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedAlways {
            if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLBeaconRegion.self) {
                if CLLocationManager.isRangingAvailable() {
                    startScanning()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
        if beacons.count > 0 {
            NSLog("Found beacon")
        } else {
            NSLog("Beacon not found")
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
        let beaconRegion = region as! CLBeaconRegion
        print("Did enter region: " + (beaconRegion.major?.stringValue)!)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
        let beaconRegion = region as! CLBeaconRegion
        print("Did exit region: " + (beaconRegion.major?.stringValue)!)
    }

    func startScanning() {
        let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6")!
        let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid, major: CLBeaconMajorValue(0), minor: CLBeaconMinorValue(1), identifier: "MyBeacon")

        beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = true
        beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = true
        beaconRegion.notifyOnExit = true

        //        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)
        locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion)
    }
}
```

Here's what my log looks like:

```
Found beacon
Found beacon
Found beacon
// App minimised and reopened here
Found beacon
Found beacon
Found beacon
Found beacon
Found beacon
Found beacon
Beacon not found
Beacon not found
Beacon not found
Beacon not found
Beacon not found
Beacon not found
```

Comment: I know that this is an old thread, but I'm wondering if did you manage to find a workaround for your problem? I'm experiencing the same issue on iOS 12.4.1 on iPhone 5S. On an iPhone XR everything work fine...

Comment: @Istvan It turned out that our batch of beacons were faulty. We ordered another batch and everything worked as it should.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense ! I am simulating the beacons, one from a Mac Book Pro (mbeacon tool) and one from an iPad (with Noteacons app), so maybe that is the problem...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the monitoring delegate callbacks `didEnter(region: region)` and `didExit(region: region)`.  Not sure why it would change things, bit it is unusual that the code starts monitoring but does not have them.

**EDIT:** After seeing updated code, I suspect the issue may be the way ranging is started.  Instead of starting it in the `didChangeAuthorization` callback, just start it in `viewDidLoad`.  The code will not crash if authorization has not been given.  It just won't actually scan until it is.

Comment: I've update the code to show `didEnterRegion ` and `didExitRegion `. Nothing gets printed from either of the function though. Also, my major=0. I read that the major and minors start from 1 onwards. But i don't have the pin to change anything on the beacon at the moment. Would the major being 0 be a problem?

Comment: No, major and mnor being 0 are perfectly legal.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Hey David, i tried what you said. I put the `startScanning()` function in `viewDidLoad` and commented out `didChangeAuthorization `. It still doesn't detect the beacon if i minimise the app and bring it back up. But again, if i comment out `locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)` it detects the beacon after i get the app back to foreground.

Comment: Curious.  What if you uninstall your app from the iOS device, then re-run?

Comment: I've uninstalled and run it a bunch of time. It hasn't worked though. But i changed my permissions from `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription ` to `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in `info.plist` and changed `requestAlwaysAuthorization` to `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` and it works. But that doesn't solve my problem. i need it working in the background all the time.

Comment: Well, this should work.  I do not see anything else wrong.  I essentially do the same on a number of apps successfully.  Lame suggestion I know, but have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Haha, well now it works when i open the app for the first time after the restart. But it returns back to normal once i shut the app and open it the second time over. I'm thinking that its my phone acting up. Would you have a repository with a simple app like this that does monitoring which works on your device? I could then try it on mine and then finally conclude whether there's a problem with the app or my device. Thanks a lot for your help btw!

Comment: Turns out many others seem to have the same problem. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63792 

I tested my code on 2 iphone 5s's which replicated the problem i have above. But it worked fine on the iphone 5 and the iphone 6+.

Comment: I have seen that thread.  But yours sounds like a different issue as you have correlated ranging being broken with starting monitoring.

Comment: This too is the same problem i have. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39638067/swift2-3-code-for-beacon-detection?noredirect=1#comment66581038_39638067
I wonder if there's a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

Interaction with iBeacons can be done with ranging en monitoring. Ranging for a beacon provides you the value/data of the iBeacon, like uuid, major & minors.
The problem with ranging is that apple accepts only a few (circa 10 seconds) of ranging time in the background. Monitoring can be done in the background. You should check if you can range in background (print/logs) ifso, detecting the ibeacon is the problem.

ps: When you start ranging inside a region the didEnter delegate method doesn't get called, because you are already in the region.

Comment: My monitoring does sort of work. I can send notifications when i exit or enter the beacon range. My problem occurs with ranging once i minimise and reopen the app. If i add the line `locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)` in my code, my app stops detecting my beacons once i minimise and reopen then app. If i shut the app and open it afresh, it seems to start working again. But i need it to work after i reopen it once its been minimised.